# Null pointer exception on getEmail() in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to get email address of a user from firebase.This email address is uses to check the user is authenticated with email or phone number.

```
   user=mAuth.getCurrentUser ;
    if(user.getEmail!=null){
    ......do something
    }
    else{
    ......do something
    }
```

But,My problem is when i want to start this activity that closes and raise null pointer exception.How can i fix this problem.?

Comment: If you want to raise `NullPointerException`, just type `throw new NullPointerException()`.

Comment: Unless you're code is bad formated that's not the way it should be, getCurrentUser is a method as well as getEmail not variables

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> If no user is signed in, getCurrentUser returns null: .......
>
> getCurrentUser might also return null because the auth object has not
> finished initializing.

May be because of the reasons above your user object is null and throws NullPointerException.
You should attach an [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) to get the currently signed in user.

Comment: I was just going to answer with exactly this. Good going!